# How to remove integers from a mixed numpy array containing sub-arrays and integers?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that contains both sub-arrays and an **integer**:

```
mixed_array = np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]), 0])
```

I want to mask the array so that I am left with only the sub-arrays and not the **integer**.

```
mixed_array = np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
```

I am working with very large arrays so I can't afford to use loops.

I have tried indexing in various ways on ~is_instance() and .dtype attributes. The mixed array is created by a useful package function, so it's hard to avoid creating it.

**Edit: would it be possible to convert the ints to arrays (such as: np.array([0]) for the example above?**

Comment: Don't mix types in numpy arrays. When you do that, you can't use numpy's powerful vectorized methods and must rely on slow iteration

Comment: A the subarrays all the same shape?

Comment: The sub-arrays of varying shapes and the integers to remove are randomly dispersed.

Comment: It may help to know how/why you create such list/object arrays in the first place.

Comment: result of numpy_groupies.aggregate() where func='array'... it will produce an array of sub-arrays of int elements or the int elements themselves (in the case where the row_idx and col_idx are not groups but rather correspond to the indices of the array)

Answer (score 1):

Since an object array is no better than a python list, you have to use a loop:

```
out = np.array([a for a in mixed_array if isinstance(a, np.ndarray)])
```

You can vectorize this, but it won't be more efficient:

```
isarray = np.vectorize(lambda x: isinstance(x, np.ndarray))
out = mixed_array[isarray(mixed_array)]
```

Output:

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

Always avoid to create object arrays in the first place.